# Is getsatisfaction.com a competitor to hosted/general purpose SO?

Tags: discussion

Is [getsatisfaction.com](http://getsatisfaction.com/) a knowledge exchange competitor of hosted stackoverflow engine?

DISCLAIMER: I have no professional/financial affiliation with getsatisfaction.com or stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like there's a GS for SO: http://getsatisfaction.com/stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetSatisfaction is more centered around customer support for a company.

That meaning, you have people for the company there. And users can ask questions about the product the company has.

You can see a great example of GetSatisfaction for [Adobe's version of it.](http://getsatisfaction.com/adobe)

It has features like what the mood of the users are in a said question and others that make it more support oriented.

I can see where the resemblance is though.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is more likely competition for Uservoice. It was even brought up on Uservoice that we should change to getsatisfaction from Uservoice.

Comment: I voted you up for a great way to answer - comparing to uservoice. [BTW, I think I heard on the podcast that meta.SO is an experiment to see if the SO engine could replace uservoice :)]